Which is more important for an efficient donation of electrons from an atom to the vacant orbital of a bonded atom?
Both the similarity between the size of the two atoms involved, as well as the matching of orbitals matters for the strength of electron-donation to the empty orbital of a bonded atom. The more similar the size of the atoms (B and F, or Al and Cl for example); the stronger such an interaction is, and the smaller the orbitals involved (2p-2p >2p-3p > 2p-4p > 2p>5p). But which matters more for the strength of this interaction (for example, for the strength of lewis acidity of group-13 chlorides, the order decreases down the group where 3 effects are in play-  decreasing electron-donation strength due to orbital mismatch, increasing strength of the above-mentioned interaction due to atomic size match, and effective nuclear charge.) So, when such conflicting effects are there in bonding, which the more important criterion to determine relative strength of the electron-donation?

I think this is too complicated to put into just a single heuristic between the competing factors.  Have you read this answer as an example on the complexity for answering this?

How about you check what pi backbonding actually is and stop using the word for "ordinary" donation of pi electrons from a ligand?

@Mithoron I'm sorry my understanding of back-bonding was wrong. In my class, I was taught that back-bonding occurs when an atom donates electrons to the empty orbital of a bonded atom. I'll edit my question.

@Mithoron hope its better now.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74677/why-boron-trihydride-is-weaker-lewis-acid-than-boron-tribromide-and-boron-tri-io https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89378/which-is-more-acidic-bf3-or-alcl3

Better, it's awfully common for some reason :/
